# Checking permission for a path

Tags: php

I need to code a file browser and want to implement it in a dynamic manner. (so theoretically every folder can be browsed)

To prevent access outside the root folder I thought of the following concept:

- Client never ever gets to see the absolute paths.
- The client always requests relative paths.
- Server appends root folder to relative path and converts the path with `realpath`.
- Server checks if the resulting path begins with the specified root directory.

Example:

Root folder is `/var/www` (always put through realpath first).

- Client requests `/../`
- Server appends root folder -> `/var/www//../` and calls `realpath` -> `/var/`.
- Server checks if `/var/` starts with `/var/www` -> false -> hence permission denied.

Here the implementation I thought of (crudely coded):

```php
$rootFolder = realpath('/var/www/');

function to_absolute_path($relativePath) {
    global $rootFolder; // <- i know, globals are evil >:)

    $absolutePath = $rootFolder.'/'.$relativePath;

    return realpath($absolutePath);
}

function verify_permission($absolutePath) {
    global $rootFolder;

    if (!$absolutePath) return false;

    // strlen($rootFolder) is also cacheable, i'm aware
    return substr($absolutePath, 0, strlen($rootFolder)) === $rootFolder;
}

$absolutePath = to_absolute_path($clientRequestedFile);

if (!verify_permission($absolutePath)) {
   // Permission denied
}
```

It seems to work fine but I really want to get this right to prevent nasty bugs.

Can someone confirm my logic?

**BTW**:

In the case of symlinks, I thought I would just follow the symlink and apply `verify_permission` when I arrived at the destination.

Comment: Since your code seems to work, and you just want to confirm best practice etc, you should post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. However, I think it looks solid.

Comment: Ok according to the answer(s) it seems that this is the best way to do it.